Uploaded Media being Cut / snapped (image) or Reduced Duration (video)
I have a storage service "Bunny" where I can upload my media, I'm facing a weird issue when I upload high-resolution images or videos and try to fetch the image or video I get back images cut in half horizontally or vertically (half white/half image) and videos duration reduced into few seconds.
in case of low resolution (lower than full HD) ones everything is working fine
my flow
Media -> Frontend App (React) -> multipart form -> 
-> Server (NodeJS / Fastify) -> Read file as Filestream or Buffer ->
-> PUT (application/octet-stream) -> Bunny Storage

Has anyone faced such an issue? what can be the causes, is it something related to my server or the way I'm uploading the files into the storage?
p.s not providing full code as it is not a small/short one-piece thing. but can make some snippets if it will help
I have tried different file formats and all results same. resized images worked but resizing video is not an option for now.
also tried the way I read the file on the server side like Filestream or Buffer again nothing changed.
Controller
async function createMedia(req, res) {
  if (!req.isMultipart()) {
    return res.status(400).send("Wrong content type, must use multipart/form-data")
  }

  try {
    const { eventId } = req.params
    const data = await req.file()

    const { type, tags, date, media} = data.fields
    const mediaData = {
      eventId,
      type: type?.value,
      tags: tags?.value?.split(",").map((x) => x.trim()),
      date: date?.value,
      storageId: EVENT_MEDIA_PATH,
      media
    }

    return await mediaService.createMedia(mediaData)
  } catch (e) {
    console.error("create media error", e)
    res.status(402).send(e)
  }
}

Service
async function createMedia({
  date,
  type,
  tags,
  eventId,
  storageId,
  media,
}) {
  const mediaName = await storageService.handleFileUpload(EVENT_MEDIA_PATH, media)

  return Media.create({
      date,
      type,
      tags,
      eventId,
      storageId,
      mediaName,
  })

PUT logic
const handleFileUpload = async (storagePath, file) => {
  const filename = generateFileSlug(file.filename)

  const response = await axios.put(
    `https://${HOSTNAME}/${STORAGE_ZONE_NAME}/${storagePath}/${filename}`,
    file.file,
    {
      headers: {
        AccessKey: ACCESS_KEY,
        "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream"
      }
    }
  )

  if (response.data) {
    return filename
  }
}


It would be helpful to see the PUT logic

@ManuelSpigolon I've added the flow code. thanks

Seems good - did you set the bodyLimit?

@ManuelSpigolon no i didn't set any body limits

Could you try to set it as bigger as the high-res file?

@ManuelSpigolon I set it to 25mb but it is the same.
